# Instagram login in phonegap ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, instagram, instagram-api

I am new in phone gap.I am trying to implement Instagram Login for Phone-gap iphone. facinfg some problem for calling the method of the plugin.cordova2.9.0 version  i am using.Here is the following code:

CDVInstagramPlugin.js

```
function startLogin(response)
{`enter code here`
   cordova.exec(onInstaComplete, onInstaNotComplete, 'LoginViewController', 'initWithWebView', []);

}


//  LoginViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *loginWebView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView* loginIndicator;
    IBOutlet UILabel *loadingLabel;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *typeOfAuthentication;
-(void)startLogin;
@end




  LoginViewController.m
//  InstagramUnsignedAuthentication


#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL                               @"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/"
#define INSTAGRAM_APIURl                                @"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"
#define INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID                             @"808a4481a80a4f9da83d3596d9e90a53"
#define INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET                         @"a997b61ab50847278170344873ddcb3b"
#define INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI                          @"http://localhost/newdata/"
#define INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN                          @"access_token"
#define INSTAGRAM_SCOPE                                 @"likes+comments+relationships"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize typeOfAuthentication;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}

-(void)initWithWebView//:(UIWebView *)web
{
    NSLog(@"Startlogin call");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
//    loginWebView=web;

    loginWebView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    NSString* authURL = nil;

    if ([typeOfAuthentication isEqualToString:@"UNSIGNED"])
    {
        authURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=True",
                   INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,
                   INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                   INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI,
                   INSTAGRAM_SCOPE];
    }
    else
    {
        authURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=code&scope=%@&DEBUG=True",
                   INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,
                   INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                   INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI,
                   INSTAGRAM_SCOPE];
    }

    [loginWebView setDelegate:self];
    [loginWebView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: authURL]]];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark delegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [self checkRequestForCallbackURL: request];
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [loginIndicator startAnimating];
    loadingLabel.hidden = NO;
    [loginWebView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    loginWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.1 animations:^{
      //  loginWebView.alpha = 0.2;
    }];
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [loginIndicator stopAnimating];
    loadingLabel.hidden = YES;
    [loginWebView.layer removeAllAnimations];
    loginWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.1 animations:^{
        //loginWebView.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self webViewDidFinishLoad: webView];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark auth logic


- (BOOL) checkRequestForCallbackURL: (NSURLRequest*) request
{
    NSString* urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    if ([typeOfAuthentication isEqualToString:@"UNSIGNED"])
    {
        // check, if auth was succesfull (check for redirect URL)
          if([urlString hasPrefix: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI])
         {
             // extract and handle access token
             NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString: @"#access_token="];
             [self handleAuth: [urlString substringFromIndex: range.location+range.length]];
             return NO;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        if([urlString hasPrefix: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI])
        {
            // extract and handle access token
            NSRange range = [urlString rangeOfString: @"code="];
            [self makePostRequest:[urlString substringFromIndex: range.location+range.length]];
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)makePostRequest:(NSString *)code
{

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=%@&code=%@",INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,INSTAGRAM_CLIENTSERCRET,INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI,code];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *requestData = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"]];
    [requestData setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [requestData setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [requestData setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [requestData setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response = NULL;
    NSError *requestError = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestData returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    [self handleAuth:[dict valueForKey:@"access_token"]];

}

- (void) handleAuth: (NSString*) authToken
{
    NSLog(@"successfully logged in with Tocken == %@",authToken);

}


@end
```

Config.xml

```
<feature name="LoginViewController">
    <param name="ios-package" value="LoginViewController" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Please let me know if another way for this or anything i doing wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@subir,

You are using outdated code examples.

YOu have hit:

[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

You have hit 11. and 12.

**11. You need to get your plugins from NPM now.**

The rules regarding sourcing your plugins can be rather confusing. The best thing to do is read the blog posts - below. Developers that use **CLI** can source from github, again see the blog post.

2015-10-09 - Without announcment, tweet, or blog, the repository change a full week before it was scheduled. I can do nothing, but complain.... This is damm annoying.

- NEW NEW [Cordova npm search page](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)
- NEW NEW [Cordova CORE plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html)
- [Latest version of plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/06/22/plugins-release.html) June 22, 2015

  *Blog Posts Related to #11*
- [Cordova Plugins Registry becomes immutable](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/08/CPR-readonly.html) 2015/09/08
- [Plugins Release and Moving plugins to npm](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html) 2015/04/21
- [List of the Latest *Core* Plugins and their versions](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/06/22/plugins-release.html) June 22, 2015

**12. `<feature>` is deprecated**

`<feature>` tags are deprecated. That means they are no longer used.
  You can [read about it here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_features.md.html#Features)

Comment: Sorry, did not get your response. I've been forgetting to tell people. **iOS9 is [not official support](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/current-tripping-points.md)**